# prime divisors of number of the form $32z^4+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, quadratic-reciprocity

In a proof I‘m working on, I’m trying to characterize a prime $\phi$ which divides three numbers: one of the form $2x^2+1$, one of the form $2y^4+1$, and one of the form $32z^4+1$. Using various divisibility and congruence arguments, I have it down to

$$\phi \mid 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 641 \cdot 4241 \cdot 18059.$$

The answer I‘m ultimately trying to prove is $32z^4+1=33$ (*i.e.,* $z=1$).

Are there any congruence or reciprocity arguments that would eliminate $641$, $4241$, or $18059$? A brute force search [of relatively small numbers] suggests that $641$ and $4241$ might not divide numbers of the form $32z^4+1$, but that could easily be shown false by searching on larger $z$.

---

EDIT: Here are some more details.

I have two positive integers, $p$ and $y$, which satisfy $(2p^2+1) \mid (2y^4+1)$. I have two other positive integers, $n$ and $m$, and I can characterize both $p$ and $y$ in terms of $n$ and $m$. I’ve found that if a prime $\phi \mid \gcd(2p^2+1,2y^4+1)$, then $\phi \mid (32m^4+1)$. Using that fact and other relationships I have between the various numbers involved, I’ve reduced the possibilities for $\phi$ to $3,11,641,4241,18059$. I want to prove $32m^4+1=33$, *i.e.,* $m=1$. I’m hoping I can eliminate some or all of the possibilities for $\phi$ other than $3$ and $11$, and then use power arguments to find $32m^4+1=33$.

---

EDIT #2: As it turns out, I was able to take another path and prove $\phi \mid 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 257 \cdot 1171$, so I don’t need the answer to this question in order to move forward on my work. But I’m leaving it up/open, because I am interested in hearing comments and answers!

Comment: I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something, but it looks like a number $q$ which divides $32z^4+1$ automatically divides numbers of the other two forms, with $2z\mid y$ and $4y^2\mid x$. Is this as intended?

Comment: @abiessu: Hmmm… yes, I see how it could be interpreted that way. In the proof I’m working on, I’m looking for $\phi \mid (2p^2+1)$ and $\phi \mid (32m^4+1)$, with $p=n^2+2mn-m^2$ [for another number $n$]. So the situation is not quite as simple as what you’re describing…

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Lots of primes divide numbers of the form $32z^4+1$, not just the ones you listed.  Are there other restrictions?

Comment: Easy brute force computer searches show that $32 x^4 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod p$ has no solutions for $p = 641$ and $4241$, but $32 x^4 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 18059$ for $x = 6276$ and $11783$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I only went up to $x=10^6$ in my brute force search… Are we sure there aren’t solutions with [much] larger $x$? I would love an airtight (*e.g.,* congruence- or reciprocity-based) proof that those primes can be eliminated.

Comment: @lulu: In my proof so far, I have [I believe?] proven that $3,11,641,4241,18059$ are the only possible values of $\phi$. So, yes, there are “other restrictions“, but they would be found in the rest of my [ongoing] proof of the theorem I’m attacking.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan, You want for example $641\nmid 32z^4+1$? if so we may write: $32z^4+1=2(2z)^4+1)-1$, also if $(a, 641)=1$ we can write $a^{640}-1\bmod 641$, that means we have to have: $2[(2z)^4+1]=a^{640}$. So we have to look for such a and filter it.